# Web Scraping Fbref table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, domain-data-modelling

My code so far, works for different table on FBref website, however struggling to get player details. The below code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


url = 'https://fbref.com/en/squads/18bb7c10/Arsenal-Stats'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

table = BeautifulSoup(soup.select_one('#stats_standard').find_next(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, Comment)), 'html.parser')

#print some information from the table to screen:
for tr in table.select('tr:has(td)'):
tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
print('{:<30}{:<20}{:<10}'.format(tds[0], tds[3], tds[5]))
```

gives me the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'
```

Comment: You're getting this error as you are getting NoneType object from select_one. This is because '#stats_standard' can't be found, to be selected.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post by removing the code (rolled back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

As mentioned, there is no table with id `stats_standard` the id should be `stats_standard_10728`

#### How to fix and go a bit generic

Change your table selector to:

```
table = soup.select_one('table[id^="stats_standard"]')
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


url = 'https://fbref.com/en/squads/18bb7c10/Arsenal-Stats'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.select_one('table[id^="stats_standard"]')

#print some information from the table to screen:
for tr in table.select('tr:has(td)'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
    print('{:<30}{:<20}{:<10}'.format(tds[0], tds[3], tds[5]))
```

#### Just in case

You can make your life much easier using pandas [read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-html) to grab, display and modify table data.

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://fbref.com/en/squads/18bb7c10/Arsenal-Stats')[0]
```

---

Need to know, how to handle commented tables? Check -> [How to scrape table from fbref could not be found by BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548912/how-to-extract-table-from-a-webpage-using-its-id/77548971#77548971)