# how to extract table from a webpage using its id?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to gather some data for a data analysis project concerning italian football. Unfortunately I can't extract one specific `table` from the web page, even though the `id` is correct.

The code is the following one:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://fbref.com/it/comp/11/gca/Statistiche-di-Serie-A#all_stats_gca"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'stats_gca'})

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

print(df)
```

With this `id` ('stats_squads_gca_for') I have no problem, but with  ('stats_gca') in my example I get no `table` as output and also the compiler says that there is no such table.

What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried by not using pandas but the result is the same. I expect to have missed something.

Comment: did you try `read_html(url)` ?

Comment: page may use `JavaScript` to generate table - but `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`. And server may also send different `HTML` for different browser (and different HTML when browser can't run `JavaScript`) so first check what you really have in `response.content`

Comment: @Walrus - I slightly adapted your example in the question by inserting the id with which it does not work, I think that makes the question easier to understand, after all we want to see the code that needs to be debugged. May take a minute or two taking the [tour] and read [ask]. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is hidden in [comments](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#special-strings) , so simplest solution would be to remove the comments:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url= 'https://fbref.com/it/comp/11/gca/Statistiche-di-Serie-A#all_stats_gca'
pd.read_html(
    requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
    ,attrs={'id':'stats_gca'}
)[0]
```

In addition also check the `attrs` parameter of [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to select the `table` by its `id`.